# Após incluir o UPDATE abaixo começou o erro: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: ** SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

````
require_once("../../conexao.php");

$id_sel   = $_POST['id_col'];
$nome     = $_POST['nome_col'];
$email    = $_POST['email_col'];
$nivel    = $_POST['nivel_col'];
$cpf      = $_POST['cpf_col'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco_col'];
$nroend   = $_POST['nroend_col'];
$compl    = $_POST['compl_col'];
$bairro   = $_POST['bairro_col'];
$cidade   = $_POST['cidade_col'];
$uf       = $_POST['uf_col'];
$cep      = $_POST['cep_col'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone_col'];

$email_anterior = $_POST['email_antigo'];
$cpf_anterior   = $_POST['cpf_antigo'];
$id_anterior    = $_POST['id_antigo'];

if($nome == "") {
    echo "O nome é obrigatório!";
    exit();
}

if($email == "") {
    echo "O email é obrigatório!";
    exit();
}

if($nivel == "") {
    echo "O tipo é obrigatório!";
    exit();
}

if($cpf == "") {
    echo "O cpf é obrigatório!";
    exit();
}


if ($cpf_anterior != $cpf) { 
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ebacolaborador WHERE col_cpf = '$cpf'");
    $res = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_reg = @count($res);
    if ($total_reg = @count($res) > 0) {
        echo 'O CPF já existe no arquivo';
        exit();
    }
}

if ($email_anterior != $email) { 
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ebacolaborador WHERE col_email = '$email'");
    $res = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_reg = @count($res);
    if ($total_reg = @count($res) > 0) {
        echo 'O Email pertence a outra pessoa';
        exit();
    }
}

if ($id_anterior == "") {
    $res = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ebacolaborador SET 
    col_nome     = :nome, 
    col_email    = :email, 
    col_senha    = :senha, 
    col_nivel    = :nivel, 
    col_cpf      = :cpf, 
    col_endereco = :endereco, 
    col_nroend   = :nroend, 
    col_compl    = :compl, 
    col_bairro   = :bairro, 
    col_cidade   = :cidade, 
    col_uf       = :uf, 
    col_cep      = :cep, 
    col_telefone = :telefone");

    $res2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ebausuarios SET 
    usr_nome  = :nome, 
    usr_email = :email, 
    usr_senha = :senha,
    usr_nivel = :nivel, 
    usr_cpf   = :cpf");

    $res->bindValue(":senha",    '123');
        
} else {
    $res = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ebacolaborador SET 
    col_nome     = :nome, 
    col_email    = :email, 
    col_nivel    = :nivel, 
    col_cpf      = :cpf, 
    col_endereco = :endereco, 
    col_nroend   = :nroend, 
    col_compl    = :compl, 
    col_bairro   = :bairro, 
    col_cidade   = :cidade, 
    col_uf       = :uf, 
    col_cep      = :cep, 
    col_telefone = :telefone WHERE col_id = $id_anterior"); 

** Após incluir o UPDATE abaixo começou o erro: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException:
** SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 

    $res2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ebausuarios SET 
    usr_nome     = :nome, 
    usr_email    = :email, 
    usr_nivel    = :nivel, 
    usr_cpf      = :cpf WHERE usr_cpf = $cpf_anterior");

    //bindValue pode passar qualquer tipo de parâmentro (strings, variáveis)
    //bindParam pode passar somente variáveis
    // $res->bindValue(":id_sel",   $id_anterior);
}
$res->bindValue(":nome",     $nome);
$res->bindValue(":email",    $email);
$res->bindValue(":nivel",    $nivel);
$res->bindValue(":cpf",      $cpf);
$res->bindValue(":endereco", $endereco);
$res->bindValue(":nroend",   $nroend);
$res->bindValue(":compl",    $compl);
$res->bindValue(":bairro",   $bairro);
$res->bindValue(":cidade",   $cidade);
$res->bindValue(":uf",       $uf);
$res->bindValue(":cep",      $cep);
$res->bindValue(":telefone", $telefone);

$res2->bindValue(":nome",     $nome);
$res2->bindValue(":email",    $email);
$res2->bindValue(":nivel",    $nivel);
$res2->bindValue(":cpf",      $cpf);

$res->execute();
$res2->execute();

echo 'Salvo com Sucesso!';
?>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual banco de dados você usa, mas em todos os bancos relacionais que eu conheço, a sintaxe de INSERT não é `'INSERT INTO tabela SET'`.

O correto seria `'INSERT INTO tabela (lista de campos) VALUES (lista de valores)';`

Segue uma explicação básica: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Mas tem outra coisa que você está misturando, você está usando `bindValue` do PDO em alguns momentos e concatenando as variáveis diretamente no SQL em outros momentos.

O melhor é utilizar o `bindValue` ou `bindParam` em todos os pontos, inclusive no WHERE onde você está concatenando. Ao concatenar diretamente no SQL, você está abrindo brechas para para SQL Injection, uma das premissas do PDO é justamente minimizar esse tipo de brecha.